# Grouping and bucketing a dataset

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, jupyter-notebook

I have the following dataset:

```
+-------+--------+---------------+----------+
| store | loc_id | competitor_id | distance |
+-------+--------+---------------+----------+
| 1     | 235467 | 567           | 1        |
| .     | .      | .             | .        |
| .     | .      | .             | .        |
| .     | .      | .             | .        |
| 1200  | 236667 | 7890          | 70       |
+-------+--------+---------------+----------+
```

Where:

`store`: has the unique numbers for each store - total of 1200

`loc_id`: has the unique location number for each store - total of 1200

`competitors`: has a variety of competitors IDs. - total of 600

`distance`: has the distance a competitor is from the store in miles - up to 70 miles

This dataset is massive, around 5 million rows.

The `competitors` can repeat per store since they might be in different distances, and also repeat thorough different stores meaning:

```
+-------+--------+---------------+----------+
| store | loc_id | competitor_id | distance |
+-------+--------+---------------+----------+
| 1     | 235467 | 567           | 1        |
| 1     | 235467 | 567           | 20       |
| 65    | 235532 | 567           | 5        |
+-------+--------+---------------+----------+
```

I need to aggroup the occurrences of each competitor within buckets of distances where the resulting dataset would be the following:

```
+-------+--------+---------------+---------------+----------------+----------+
| store | loc_id | competitor_id | under_10miles | ten_to_20miles | above_20 | 
+-------+--------+---------------+---------------+----------------+----------+
| 1     | 235467 | 567           | 2             | 0              | 15       |
| .     | .      | .             | .             | .              | .        |
| .     | .      | .             | .             | .              | .        |
| .     | .      | .             | .             | .              | .        |
| 1200  | 236667 | 7890          | 1             | 5              | 0        |
+-------+--------+---------------+---------------+----------------+----------+
```

meaning:

There are two 567 competitor, under 10 miles distance, from the store number 1.

I am using Jupyter notebook, so any help in Python or Pandas would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `groupby().value_counts()`:

```
(df.groupby(['store', 'loc_id', 'competitor_id'])
   ['distance'].value_counts(bins=[-1, 10, 20, np.inf])
   .unstack(level=-1, fill_values=0)
)
```

Or `pd.crosstab` with `pd.cut`:

```
pd.crosstab([df['store'], df['loc_id'], df['competitor_id']],
            pd.cut(df['distance'], bins=[-1,10,20, np.inf],
                   labels=['<10', '10-20', '>20'])
           )
```

Comment: Can you elaborate the bins arguments? I am correct to assume that the -1 represent the direction of the bucket value? eg.: to the left of 10, to the left of 20?
np.inf will take everything above 20 right?
In the first example the unstack(level=-1) what does that mean?

Thank you for your answer

Comment: Yes, it represents the thresholds, -1 to 10, 10 to 20, 20 to infinity (np.inf). First approach returns a series with 4-level index, bin being the last; `unstack(level=-1)` promotes/pivots that level to columns.